# How to monitor external webpage for changes in Azure?

Tags: azure

Can Azure monitor an external webpage for changes, and then trigger a logic app?

I read about [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/), but appears to be for internal Azure apps only, not external sites.

If there's no native service, then i assume i'll have to code my own monitor, to poll on a schedule. If so, is a Logic App (with a Recurrence) the best tool for this?

Comment: What kind of changes are you talking about?

Comment: Logic App with recurrence is probably the easiest. Depending on what you need to happen after and your skillset, Azure Functions may be a better move.

Comment: @PeterBons Change in the text or other contents of the visible page.

Comment: @KonTheCat For other programming, I think of `function` as code which returns a value based on input, and `logic` as code which performs actions without necessarily returning anything. Does it mean the same in Azure?

Comment: @johnywhy Not really. Azure Functions and Logic Apps are different services. They can either return values to other processes or not, that depends on your design. Logic Apps are good if you want to minimize coding and use third-party connectors to connect to services, Azure Functions are good if you want to write your own code (this being a substantial over-simplification, but good enough to start with). But I guess in a very default case what you are saying can hold.

Comment: @KonTheCat So the main difference is logic apps are code free, and functions are custom code?

Comment: @johnywhy That's the high-level, yes. Now with a logic app of any complexity you will start writing expressions using the Logic App expression language, which can get annoying. But you benefit from so much code being written for you as far as interacting with Azure, M365, and other services that it's typically worthwhile. Basically, there will be a point somewhere between the complexity of what you need to do, your coding skill, and the availability of connectors in Logic Apps that will decide which service makes sense. Also for CICD/git Azure Functions are much easier.